# How can I map an enum to a boolean with mapstruct?

Tags: java, enums, boolean, mapstruct

I have some auto-generated enums that I need to map to boolean values in a MapStruct mapper. They go like this:

```
enum YN {
    Y("Y"), N("N")
}

enum ZO {
    _0("0"), _1("1")
}
```

I've tried to use @ValueMappings(), but it didn't work:

```
@ValueMappings({
    @ValueMapping(source="Y", target=true),
    @ValueMapping(source="N", target=false)
)
Boolean map(YN value);
```

How can I implemente this mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ValueMappings](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-enum-types) are used for mapping between two `Enum`s. You can't use them to map an `Enum` to something else. For your defined mapping you will have to write a mapping by yourself. Then MapStruct can use that one in other mappers.

```
abstract class Mapper {
    Boolean map(YN value) {
        return YN.Y.equals(value);
    }

    Boolean map(ZO value) {
        return ZO.O.equals(value);
    }
}
```